# How to get count of wod_qty_req?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Table :wod_det
In wod_det table i want count for wod_qty_req for all orders
means wod_nbr is a work order for each order there will be component items will be there i.e wod_part for these wod_part there will be wod_qty_req so what i want is each work  order i nee count of wod_qty_req for all wod_part i tried like this

```
{us/mf/mfdtitle.i}
def var site like si_site no-undo.
for first si_mstr no-lock where si_mstr.si_domain = global_domain:
      site = si_site.
end.
for each wod_det where wod_domain = global_domain and wod_site = site no-lock break by wod_nbr by wod_part:

        if first-of(wod_nbr) then
        do:
            accumulate wod_qty_req (count).
            if last-of(wod_part) then
                do:
                    disp wod_nbr wod_part wod_qty_req (accum count wod_qty_req).
                end.
        end.

end.
```

i don't know whether this is correct or not but i didnt get any output for this plz help me out this to resolve? 
Thanks in advance..

[Here is the Image of table wod_det](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpi9P.png)

answer:

```
define variable iCount as integer no-undo.                                      
{us/mf/mfdtitle.i}                                                              
def var site like si_site no-undo.                                              
def var total like wod_qty_req initial 0 no-undo.                               
  for first si_mstr no-lock where si_mstr.si_domain = global_domain:              
      site = si_site.                                                              
  end.                                                                                      
      for each wod_det no-lock where wod_domain = global_domain              
                          and wod_site = site break by wod_nbr: 
          disp wod_nbr wod_part wod_qty_req(total by wod_nbr).                        
      end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited: based on more information.

I personally never use the `ACCUM`, `ACCUMULATE` etc functions but that might be my personal preferences.

NB: I don't know exactly what fields correspond to the information in the image so I will describe this in "pseudo" code. Exchange [WORK_ORDER_FIELD] field names to match the correct field in your database!

```
define variable iCount as integer no-undo.
{us/mf/mfdtitle.i}
def var site like si_site no-undo.
for first si_mstr no-lock where si_mstr.si_domain = global_domain:
   site = si_site.
end.

for each wod_det no-lock where wod_domain = global_domain 
                           and wod_site = site 
                           break by wod_det.[WORK_ORDER_FIELD]:

    iCount = 0.
    if first-of(wod_det.[WORK_ORDER_FIELD]) then do: 
        iCount = iCount + 1.
    end.
    display od_det.[WORK_ORDER_FIELD] iCount.
end.
```

Comment: i attached wod_det table image in question there u can see detail what i want is: if you observe work order 1139, 6 items there and also corresponding quantity req is there so i need to caluculate count for quantity req for all 6 items of work order 1139 clear?

Comment: @LovelyBobby Did that help?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working                                                                                 ** Unable to understand after -- "site  break by". (247)               
** Cannot identify a field or expression after BY keyword. (411)         
**  Line 10 --Invalid FOR, DO, REPEAT, or EDITING statement. (194)            i am getting above errors while compiling

Comment: Perhaps you can add your new code to the original question?

Comment: but your program will give only count i want total of wod_qty_req for each item in every work order